# Filepath of File Where SRO Method was Called

Tags: php

I have a class:

```
Class General
{
    ...
}
```

And I am accessing a method, like this, from another file:

```
General::the_method($params);
```

Is there a way to determine, from WITHIN the class, the filepath of WHERE the method was called? Not the filepath of the General class, but of the separate function, prbably many folders away, that has called the method?

I've tried `ReflectionClass::getFileName()`, however it seems this only works on fully instantiated objects (ie, if I'd done `$general = new General`, which I don't want to do). I figured it wouldn't work given the description of the functionality but I thought I'd give it a try. No dice, sadly.

So: is this possible?

EDIT: We are trying to accomplish this WITHOUT a second parameter passed to the function.

Comment: Can you pass it in as a 2nd argument or a param? Are you trying to figure out where it is getting called from?

Comment: @mkaatman - we actually have a similar method that works with two parameters - we're trying to eliminate the necessity of the second parameter.

Comment: @PaulCrovella - trying that now!

Comment: Is it for temporary troubleshooting or is this planned for production?

Comment: This is planned for a production environment.

Comment: `debug_backtrace` did the trick beautifully! However I do wonder if its really good coding to use it for this purpose. It's certainly not the intended usage.

Comment: Well, for a little context, we're running an auto-translation function (pulling translations from a database), and some of those translations will differ depending on the exact view they're coming from. So we're trying to automatically detect which view the translation request is coming from. Like I said, probably NOT the intended usage of `debug_backtrace`.

Comment: Well its not information we're trying to 'glean from a filename', translations are explicitly saved with a relation to specific filename, if applicable. But your point is well taken about automagically determined filenames. However, we're trying to avoid needing to go through thousands of PHP files and change the formatting of all our translate functions.